# Practical differences of two types of tile levelling system

Tags: tile, tiling, leveling

I'm looking to tile a relatively small area floor (about 4 sq m) with ceramic tiles 300x100 mm, 10mm thick. There are two main types of tile levelling systems that I've seen: clip and wedge

[image]

and the screw-cap type ones

[image]

What are the practical differences between the two?  How to choose one or the the other? Or is this purely down to what I prefer to work with?

<sub>Please note that these images are purely for display purposes, I don't have any preferences at present on specific brands.</sub>

Comment: I just noticed the size of your tiles...  The leveling systems I have seen (in the US) are recommended for large format tiles (greater than 300mmx300mm).  It think any system would be more trouble than it's worth for smaller tiles.

Comment: if small and not too crooked, try a self-leveling underlayment.

Comment: I agree with @JPhi1618 - for that small an area and those reasonably small tiles, a level and a few gentle taps with a mallet should suffice to get your tiles level. Make sure you follow the manufacturer's directions on the size of trowel notch to ensure you've got plenty of thinset underneath them and they should settle in nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that these leveling systems are both more effective for larger format tiles. However, I think the question is good and one I had trouble finding an answer to when I was tiling my kitchen.

### Re-use

- Wedge: The wedge is re-usable, the plastic tab is broken off.
- Screw/Spin: The spin top is re-usable, the plastic tab is broken off.

### Tools

- Wedge: To get the right pressure, a special tool is needed
- Screw/Spin: The spin top is re-usable, the plastic tab is broken off. No special tools are needed.

### Corners

- Wedge: The wedges are really intended to go across two tiles, so for a corner, you need 4 wedges.
- Screw/Spin: The spin top can sit directly on a corner or a T and provide leveling across each tile.

### Shifting

- Wedge: The wedge pushes both tiles in the same direction, which is not a problem if you have spacers between the tiles.
- Screw/Spin: The spinning action of the top can cause the tiles to shift in different directions as you tighten them. This can cause the tile to twist slightly, even with spacers.

### Availability

Both systems were available through a certain orange big box store (I found the wedge-type in-stock, and the Screw type needed to be ordered online).

### My Experience

I ended up trying the wedge type first, then switched to the screw type. I found that the upward pressure of the wedge on the plastic could cause the tab to break prematurely (and you have to pull the tile up to put a new tab in). With the screw type, I could tighten, loosen, re-tighten as needed. I could also put one screw type at the corner intersection of 4 tiles. In the end, I was very happy with the result using the screw-type.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the wedge clips that I have seen require (or strongly recommend) a special tool for tightening the wedge because hand force is unlikely to get it properly tight.  On one hand, the screw type doesn't need a tool and on the other hand, the screw type doesn't have a tool so it could be tiring for your hands.

Another issue is re-use.  For the wedge systems, the wedges can be used over and over again, and once you snap them off, the wedge is reusable immediately with no extra work.  For the screw type, you have to unscrew that little broken off shaft before you can reuse the red cap.  That seems annoying to me.

That said, these are a few tiny differences that I can see.  They both do the same job.  Cost will be an important factor as well, but I can't speak to that.

I just got finished using some [of these](https://www.rubi.com/us/tile-level-quick-kit-r614) and they were pretty... ok.  Not great, not bad.  Pros and cons were a cross between your wedges and the screw caps.